# Hover Over Photo Effect Wordpress Plugin Or?

Tags: wordpress, hover

I like the effect of this site's photos http://www.atlanticbt.com/employees.php - is there a wordpress plugin or what's the easiest way to achieve this?

The effect I like is that you can hover over the image and then the image is a description/bio. I don't necessarily need it linked to another page.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a CSS trick: take a look at this fiddle: I have an image and on hover, i make its background red. You can set any property to show on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/AuLtx/2/

```
 .image-css{
   height:45px;
   width:45px;
   float:left;
  }  

  .a:hover .image-css{
   background-color:red;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Now what if I wanted it to have a hover over text, not an image with text? Sort of like this pop up-like effect: http://www.spiceworks.com/jobs/meet-the-team/

Comment: so in that case, it looks like that there is a hidden <div class="showme" style="display:none">show me something what ever I put in this </div> Now you can do .a:hover .showme{ display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin you are looking for. Hope it helps you. [wp-visual-slide-box-builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/)